# How to test a cryptography program?

Tags: c++, cryptography

I've created a code(C++) that encrypts an file. It generates a key and the encrypted file. But I don't know how good(or bad) is my algorithm. Is there any way that I can test it?

Comment: At the very least, you want to be sure it can be decrypted.

Comment: Do something illegal with it and see if you're caught? ;)  Or put all your identity on the www with it and see if you're broke? ;)

Comment: Offer a $10,000 reward to the first person who cracks the algorithm?  ;) (more seriously, verifying cryptographic algorithms is hard specifically because the purpose of the algorithms is to thwart other people who are very likely smarter and/or more experienced than you (or I) are... in general I'd say that unless you are already a cryptography expert, *and* your algorithm has already been reviewed by and passed muster with a number of other cryptography experts, then it is safe to say the algorithm is breakable without much difficulty by someone who knows what he/she is doing)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner's answer is the correct one -- that's what the pros (like hardcore white-hat university/corporate projects) do!

Comment: The first question that comes to my mind is: did you make up your own algorithm, or implement someone else's?

Comment: Ok. I think I got the point. First: Yes I can decrypt the file. Second: offering a reward is actually a good idea, but... OMG where is the money? I was expecting something different, but 
assumed that I could get this answer. Nice detail: I have absolutely no idea of how I can break my code, unless I have the key.

Comment: @John Perry I made my own algorithm

Comment: If you're foolish enough to write your own encryption algorithm, you can be foolish enough to just presume it works, encrypt all of your personal data with it, and relax. No need to be aware at all of the fact that billions of dollars each year are spend on developing secure encryption (and trying to defeat it), because certainly your own algorithm is perfect. Those other people are just idiots with extra money to spend for nothing.

Comment: My algorithm is a modified combination of other kwnon algorithm. I'm not it's perfect, actually, none oh then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never count on the secrecy of your encryption algorithm. This would be a big strategic mistake for many reasons. For the least, if ever this algorithm is revealed, it will be very difficult to change it and re-install a patch that uses another algorithm on all the machines that use your software. On the other hand, changing a key is easier and does not require any software modification.

The first step to ensure its robustness is to *publish it*. Yes, and when you try to assess it, *assume* that is known to the intruder (Trudy), who only lacks the *key*.

Having in mind that Trudy knows the algorithm, assess the level of robustness of your algorithm by asking yourself the following questions:

- Does it resist *Cipher-Only* cryptanalysis? If Trudy has a (big enough) set of texts ciphered with the same key, but she has some information, such as the language with which the texts are written, the subject of these texts (i.e financial letters), will she be able to deduce that key? Trudy could do a brute force attack by searching all possible keys (hence the key should be big enough, at least 128 bits in modern cryptography), but she could also reduce the search by making guesses based on some known statistics on the language, the subject and other information.
- Does it resist *Known-Plaintext* cryptanalysis? If Trudy has a set of ciphered texts together with the corresponding plain texts, can she deduce the key?
- Does it resist *Chosen Plaintext* cryptanalysis? If Trudy has open access to a system that can generate for her the ciphertext of any plaintext, can she deduce the key? (notice that this is a requirement for public-key crypto-systems, such as TLS).

As a conclusion, you can see that cryptanalysis is a serious and very advanced science, so, if you are doing this for a serious project and not for fun, it is highly non-recommended to write your private algorithm, but to select off the shelf one of the publicly known algorithms, because they have been validated and their robustness proven throughout years.

Comment: That is what I was expecting. But let's go step by step. Let me give a resumed explanation of my algorithm: It converts each file character to a number(this is made randomly). Than it shuffle each digit of these numbers. Finally, it tranforms the shuffled numbers to ASCII.

So, i think very improbable that the Trudy will use the first method(did I mentioned that the generated key has both radom size and value?).

Comment: Let me see if I understood: the Known-Plaintext cryptanalysis and Chosen Plaintext cryptanalysis are the methodes used for beating the enigma machine, aren't they?

Comment: @RafaelMarinho no it has nothing to do with Enigma. Concerning you first question, I cannot tell unfortunately. It is extremely difficult to make an assessment of a crypto system intuitively. The answer is actually the same as above: better to select a publicly well-known algorithm with good reputation. There are so many of them, select one that fits well with your case. :)

Comment: @A.S.H Excellent answer. I'll add my two cents based on years working with cryptography: unfortunately, cryptographic algorithms cannot be _proven_ to be secure, you can only use cryptanalysis to assess how well it fares against known attack strategies. Bruce Schneier wrote an excellent paper called [A self-study course in block-cipher cryptanalysis](https://www.schneier.com/paper-self-study.pdf) that explains the task at hand quite well.

Comment: @Daniel I totally agree with you, thanks for your note! indeed, getting confidence with a cryptographic system is not a matter of formal proof, but some of it combined to some experience. the longer a system has proven to resist cryptanalysis, the more it gathers confidence.

Comment: Not that the requirements ASH mentioned are much weaker than those we generally demand from ciphers. What we ask for when evaluating unauthenticated encryption is [indistinguishability under adaptive chosen plaintext attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_indistinguishability).

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to security: never make your own algorithm.   Apply an appropriate combination of existing algorithms using a vetted, easily updatable 3rd party library.

Comment: My algorithm is a modified combination of other kwnon algorithm